# Delete Row using Sweet alert in asp.net web forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, sweetalert

```
function del() {
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
            .then((willDelete) => {
                if (willDelete) {
                  
                    swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                        icon: "success",
                    });
                } else {
                    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
                }
            });
    }
```

and my link button Code is please help me out how i can use sweet alert while using link-button within repeater

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="delete_lbtn" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
CausesValidation="false" OnClick="delete_lbtn_Click" OnClientClick="del(); return false;"> 
<i class="nav-icon i-Close-Window"> Delete</i></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: In your sweet alert are working properly? and also, you know about the ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your "return false" in your on client click event. The server side code will not run if you return false, but will if you return try.
Hence:

```
function del() {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
              
                swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                    icon: "success",
                });
                return true;
            } else {
                swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```